# Angularjs Does not work with Jquery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an web application using ASP.Net MVC5 and AngularJS 1.5, I have a page were data is display from MVC ActionResult and further Edit and Delete operation is perform using AngularJS.

But as I perform edit operation an jsonresult in call from ASP.net MVC controller and perform perfect edit operation with success result, but I also want to refresh the data that is display from MVC ActionResult so I created an partial view and use Jquery load function and pass the URL(MVC ActionResult Url).

The load function refresh the data with current changes in the database but after that AngularJS does not work even AngularJS `{{Expressions}}` are not working

```js
$http.post('myactionName',{param:param}).success(function (data){
  $('#DiV').load("mypartialActionName");
}
```

```html
<div id="DiV">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialViewName")
</div>
```

Comment: ng-view should tell you something

Comment: Use it as attribute directive in your 'body' tag

Comment: i aslo created my own directive but it does not work i face the same issue,<div my-directive></div>

Comment: @madalinivascu im new to this technology can help me with any tutortial or link

Comment: @MukeshGupta there is a forbidden site for new people that come to learn new technologies https://docs.angularjs.org

Comment: when you update something angular should automatically change the view to reflect the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> first add your jQuery and Angular files, then create the 'app' module

**Html**

```
<body configs>
<div id="DiV"> @Html.Partial("_PartialViewName") </div>
</body>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive("configs", function($http){
return {
     link: function(){
        $http.post('myactionName',{param:param}).success(function (data){
             $('#DiV').load("mypartialActionName"); 
         }
     }
}
});
```

Comment: i tierd this but im getting the same result my partialview get updated but my angularjs ng-click does not work for second time infact not only ng-click even expression value are not display but when i refresh the page ng-click start working and again i edit something,record get updated but again click stop working and i manually need to press f5

Answer (score 0):

First of all i want to say something if you are using completely AngularJs then do not use @Html.Partial()..use ng-include built in directive instead to inject external template..as of now you are totally depend on MVC that is the bad practice..you have to use MVC for only for server side not Front-end Part and AngularJs uses $http asynchronously you do not have to refresh to to retrieve your data and do not rely on JQUERY..AngularJs can tackle all the things whatever JQUERY did..